# how to take text box value from drop down list

Tags: javascript, html

i have a chunk of code in which a particular value comes in form of drop down list . i have been asked to remove that and give in text box format as there is also a single value. it's a task with time limit . the value is getting selected by different method so its time hindering to see from where it;'s taking value
i simply hide that select box and make a new text box in disabled form and taking its value from selected option. but trick is not working

```
<div id='divMtdAttach' class='clsStatsDivWhole'     
     style='display:none;background:#EEF4FD;border:none;top:20px; left:40px;'>
        <div class='clsCapTblHdr' align=left valign=center     
             style='position:absolute;left:15px; font-size:9pt; font-weight:bold; width:100%;'>

             Configuration file
        </div>
<div class='clsMtdStatPnl' style='top:45px;width:90%;'>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class='clsTblCell5' align=left valign=center>Interface &nbsp;</td>
        <td class='clsTblCell5' valign=top>
            <select id='idMethodSel' class='clsTargetSel' 
                    style='width:220px; display:none' Size=1 onchange='mtdAttachDlg("MtdAttach")'>
                    </select>

            <table class='clsTblCellTI' style='border:1px solid #7f9db9;'>
               <tr> 
                   <td id='idMethodSelTxt' 
                       style='width:210px; height:12px; padding-left:2px; padding-right:2px;border-style:none;'>
                           <script type="text/javascript">
                               showTxtbox()
                           </script>
                   </td>
               </tr>


function showTxtbox()
{
 idMethodSelTxt.innerText=idMethodSel.options[idMethodSel.selectedIndex].text;  
}
```

but this trick is not working and its throwing an error invalid object type.

Comment: Please try to edit your question to make it a little more clear what you're trying to accomplish.  It sounds like you want to replace a select dropdown with a disabled text box after a certain amount of time has passed.  Is that correct?  Plese try to use punctuation and capital letters to separate your sentences.

Comment: actually a select dropdown is already there and i have to replace it with a text box. that select drop down list through some methods is getting a property name. so i dont want to change that structure . i just want to hide that select box and get a text box hidden

Comment: Check out the fiddles in my answer.  They do exactly what you describe: they replace a select dropdown with a text box.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just guessing at what you're afer...

Here's a simple JavaScript function (using jQuery) that replaces your dropdown with a disabled text field:

```
function replaceSelectWithTextBox() {
    var $drop = $('#idMethodSel');
    var choice = $drop.val();
    var $textBox = $('<input type="text">');
    $textBox.val(choice).prop('disabled', true);
    $drop.parent('td').append($textBox);
    $drop.remove();
}
```

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chJ9p/1/) shows a working example using a 10 second timer.

Here's another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ku9Q/5/) that uses a button in stead of a timer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `idMethodSelTxt.innerText`, try `idMethodSelTxt.innerHTML`.

I am also assuming you got the `idMethodSelTxt` and `idMethodSel` variables with `document.getElementById("idMethodSelTxt")` before trying to access them.

```
function showTxtbox()
{
   var idMethodSelTxt = document.getElementById("idMethodSelTxt");
   var idMethodSel = document.getElementById("idMethodSel");
   idMethodSelTxt.innerHTML = idMethodSel.options[idMethodSel.selectedIndex].text;  
}
```